# Speed up Key Lookup (clustered)

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, execution-plan

I have a slow query in Sql 2017. Key lookup (Clustered) is taking 62%. There is also an Index Seek (nonclustered) taking 30%.

Is there anyway I can speed this query up?

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1oIcWofd

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'
SELECT TOP(@__p_4) 
    [v].[County], 
    [v].[Community], 
    [v].[DataProvider], 
    [v].[Site], 
    [v].[Latitude], 
    [v].[Longitude], 
    [v].[Elevation], 
    [v].[Instrument], 
    [v].[MonitorId], 
    [v].[ParameterId], 
    [v].[Parameter], 
    [v].[MeasurementStartTime], 
    [v].[MeasuredValue], 
    [v].[AdjustedValue], 
    [v].[Units], 
    [v].[AdjustmentDesc], 
    [v].[LowerLimitCheck], 
    [v].[UpperLimitCheck], 
    [v].[RepeatingValueCheck], 
    [v].[SpikeCheck], 
    [v].[QualityPreliminary]
FROM [vw_DownloadDataSubhourly] AS [v]
WHERE 
(
    (([v].[CountyId] = @__Parse_0) AND ([v].[MeasurementStartTime] >= @__start_1)) 
    AND ([v].[MeasurementStartTime] <= @__end_2)
) 
AND [v].[ParameterType] IN (''PM2.5'')
ORDER BY [v].[Site], [v].[MonitorId], [v].[ParameterId], [v].[MeasurementStartTime]
',
N'@__p_4 int,@__Parse_0 int,@__start_1 datetime,@__end_2 datetime',
@__p_4=750000,@__Parse_0=34,@__start_1='2019-10-01 00:00:00',@__end_2='2020-12-31 23:59:59'
```

**vw_DownloadDataSubhourly**
Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan/?id=BkiX1Vsz_

```
CREATE view [dbo].[vw_DownloadDataSubhourly] as

SELECT      
                DataProvider.DataProviderId, 
                County.CountyId, 
                Community.CommunityId, 
                County.CountyName as "County",
                Community.CommunityName as "Community",
                DataProvider.DataProviderShortName as "DataProvider", 
                Site.SiteLongName as "Site",
                SiteConfig.LatitudeTrunc as "Latitude",
                SiteConfig.LongitudeTrunc as "Longitude",
                SiteConfig.Elevation,
                Monitor.ExternalMonitorId as "MonitorId",
                Parameter.ParameterId as "ParameterId",
                Parameter.ParameterNamePublic "Parameter",
                Parameter.ParameterType "ParameterType",
                SubHourlyMeasurementData.StartDateTime "MeasurementStartTime",
                SubHourlyMeasurementData.AObs as "MeasuredValue",
                SubHourlyMeasurementData.AObsAdj as "AdjustedValue",
                UOM.UOMAbbreviation as "Units",
                AdjCode.AdjCodeDescription as "AdjustmentDesc",
                concat(MonitorConfig.MonitorMfr, ' ', MonitorConfig.MonitorModel) as "Instrument",
                case 
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF06 = '-3' then 'QC not computed'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF06 = '-2' then 'Not enough data'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF06 = '-1' then 'Not enough site/monitor info'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF06 = '0' then 'Pass'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF06 = '1' then 'Fail'
                    else NULL
                    end as "LowerLimitCheck",
                case 
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF05 = '-3' then 'QC not computed'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF05 = '-2' then 'Not enough data'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF05 = '-1' then 'Not enough site/monitor info'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF05 = '0' then 'Pass'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF05 = '1' then 'Fail'
                    else NULL
                    end as "UpperLimitCheck",
                case 
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF04 = '-3' then 'QC not computed'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF04 = '-2' then 'Not enough data'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF04 = '-1' then 'Not enough site/monitor info'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF04 = '0' then 'Pass'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF04 = '1' then 'Fail'
                    else NULL
                    end as "RepeatingValueCheck",
                case 
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF07 = '-3' then 'QC not computed'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF07 = '-2' then 'Not enough data'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF07 = '-1' then 'Not enough site/monitor info'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF07 = '0' then 'Pass'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QF07 = '1' then 'Fail'
                    else NULL
                    end as "SpikeCheck",
                case 
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QOverall = '-3' then 'QC not computed'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QOverall = '-2' then 'Not enough data'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QOverall = '-1' then 'Not enough site/monitor info'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QOverall = '0' then 'Passed all checks'
                    when SubHourlyMeasurementData.QOverall = '1' then 'Suspect'
                    else NULL
                    end as "QualityPreliminary"

FROM           SubHourlyMeasurementData 
                         INNER JOIN
                         DataProvider ON SubHourlyMeasurementData.DataProviderId = DataProvider.DataProviderId 
                         INNER JOIN
                         Site ON SubHourlyMeasurementData.SiteId = Site.SiteId AND Site.DataProviderId = DataProvider.DataProviderId
                         LEFT JOIN Community ON Site.CommunityId = Community.CommunityId
                         INNER JOIN 
                         SiteConfig ON SiteConfig.SiteId = SubHourlyMeasurementData.SiteId
                         INNER JOIN
                         County ON County.CountyId = SiteConfig.CountyId
                         INNER JOIN
                         Monitor ON Monitor.MonitorId = SubHourlyMeasurementData.MonitorId
                         INNER JOIN
                         MonitorConfig ON MonitorConfig.MonitorConfigId = SubHourlyMeasurementData.MonitorConfigId
                         INNER JOIN
                         Parameter ON Parameter.ParameterId = SubHourlyMeasurementData.ParameterId
                         INNER JOIN
                         UOM ON SubHourlyMeasurementData.UOMId = UOM.UOMId
                         LEFT JOIN
                         AdjCode ON SubHourlyMeasurementData.AdjCodeId = AdjCode.AdjCodeId
                         INNER JOIN
                         StreamSegment ON SubHourlyMeasurementData.StreamSegmentId = StreamSegment.StreamSegmentId
                         INNER JOIN 
                         MeasurementTechnique ON MeasurementTechnique.MeasurementTechniqueId = StreamSegment.MeasurementTechniqueId
                         AND MeasurementTechnique.ParameterId = SubHourlyMeasurementData.ParameterId
                         INNER JOIN
                         SamplingDuration ON SamplingDuration.SamplingDurationId = StreamSegment.SamplingDurationId
                         INNER JOIN
                         SamplingFrequencyUnits ON SamplingFrequencyUnits.SamplingFrequencyUnitsId = StreamSegment.SamplingFrequencyUnitsId

WHERE SubHourlyMeasurementData.StartDateTime >= MonitorConfig.StartDateTime and StreamSegment.IsDownloadable = 1 and SubHourlyMeasurementData.iscalculated = 1 

GO
```

Comment: Would you mind formatting your query to make it readable and adding the complete execution plan, along with all the table and index definitions?

Comment: It looks like you have a little bit of a **cardinality estimate** issue going on but can you please upload your **execution plan** to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan)?...that'll provide more information and context on your performance problems than a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you. Did not know about this site.

Answer (score 1):

So you definitely have some **wild** **cardinality estimate** issues going on based on your **execution plan** (along with some sub-performant **index scans** and warnings such as **residual I/O** issues probably resultant of the **cardinality estimate** issues).

Please see the following couple of cases where SQL Server thinks your query is only going to return a small number of rows (**Estimated Rows**) but the **Actual Rows** is **much** larger, in the tens of millions:

[image: Cardinality Estimate Issue #1]

[image: Cardinality Estimate Issue #2]

[image: Cardinality Estimate Issue #3]

Unfortunately it looks like this is all coming from the query under the hood of the view you're querying, so without knowing what that query is actually doing, it's tough to debug the issue. If you could please provide the view definition of `vw_DownloadDataSubhourly`, we should be able to help you trace the source of these **cardinality estimate** issues.

**Cardinality estimate** issues occur when the SQL Engine believes that the amount of rows an operation of your **execution plan** is going to return severely differs from the actual number of rows that are returned (usually I find when an order of magnitude of difference between those two statistics are exhibited, a **cardinality estimate** issue exists). The further off those two are, generally the worse the issue is. Especially in the case when the **Estimated Rows** are **less** than the **Actual Rows** because that means the SQL Engine provisioned less resources (e.g. Memory) than needed to serve the data for your query, hence the slow runtime.

Barring having the view definition of `vw_DownloadDataSubhourly`, the only thing I can recommend at this time is trying to [**update statistics**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the entire table for some of these one's exhibiting **cardinality estimate** issues. Here's an [additional resource](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-statistics-and-how-to-perform-update-statistics-in-sql/) regarding **statistics** and how to manually and automatically update them. For now I would recommend trying to manually update them for the following tables roughly in this order:

0. `dbo.SubHourlyMeasurementData`
1. `dbo.AdjCode`
2. `dbo.Community`
3. `dbo.SamplingFrequencyUnits`
4. `dbo.SiteConfig`
5. `dbo.Site`
6. `dbo.SamplingDuration`
7. `dbo.MonitorConfig`
8. `dbo.DataProvider`
9. `dbo.UOM`
10. `dbo.Parameter`

Unfortunately a majority of the tables referenced by your view `vw_DownloadDataSubhourly` are facing **cardinality estimate** issues.

You'll want to ensure you update the statistics with the `FULLSCAN` option to ensure you get accurate calculations on your larger tables. Also please note for larger tables, updating **statistics** could take a bit of time to run and potentially be resource intensive on the server during that time period.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on updating statistics for the tables provided. I have provided the query for the view you mentioned.

Comment: @user2570376 Thanks for updating your question with the requested information, and best of luck with **updating statistics**! After quickly reviewing the query nothing jumps out at me that would be causing such huge **cardinality estimate** issues, so I'm guessing that this is an actual case where **updating statistics** is the appropriate fix. Hopefully after you are able to update them for the tables I listed, you'll see much better performance on your next re-run. I'll take a deeper look into your view's query again in the morning, but I don't see much wrong with it. In the worst case...

Comment: ... we'll need to try re-writing the query a little but I can help with that pretty easily. Again it is seemingly suspect to having outdated **statistics** though so hopefully that's all that's needed. Please let me know how it turns out after you're able to update them.

Comment: I updated the statistics for the tables listed but it didn't seem to make a difference in the speed of the query.

Comment: @user2570376 Interesting, ok, this may require a little bit of query tuning / rewrite. Could you please add to your post the new **execution plan** your query generates now that the **statistics** are up to date? (Please leave the original **execution plan** linked as well, so they can be compared.) Again your view's query looks rather straightforward, so pretty weird you're experiencing these issues. Is there anything special going on in any of the tables it references such as **computed columns** or different **collations** / **data types** for the fields in the `WHERE` / `JOIN` clauses?

Comment: @JoshDarnell Honestly I was unaware that `FULLSCAN` wasn't the default (but I guess that makes sense) since **updating statistics** is not something I've had to manually do that much thus far. Which part of the **execution plan** shows how up to date the **statistics** are (I never went looking for that before)? Also curious on your thoughts here with OP's **cardinality estimate** issues, the numbers are pretty wild but the query under the hood looks rather basic, not seeing anything jumping out at me?

Comment: @user2570376 I'm unable to see your second **execution plan**, I think the link is broken. Could you retry re-uploading / re-linking please?

Comment: @JoshDarnell Gotcha, thank you! Always love learning how else I can put the **execution plan** to good use. :) So you think OP should try updating stats again (especially on some of those larger / more problematic tables) using the `FULLSCAN` option?

Answer (score 1):

J.D. has covered the stats bit - essentially, you might get better estimates if you have a more representative stats sample for the indexes on the `SubHourlyMeasurementData` table.  Right now it's only sampling around 1% of the rows in the table:

[image: Screenshot of stats details]

Here we can see that the stats have been updated (ModificationCount is 0), but the SamplingPercent was only 1.41871.  SQL Server picks this percentage automatically based on the number of rows in the table.

You can try updating stats with `FULLSCAN`, which might take a while:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.SubHourlyMeasurementData
WITH FULLSCAN;
```

If that helps you can work down to a more manageable percentage that still solves the problem:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.SubHourlyMeasurementData
SAMPLE 50 PERCENT;
```

Regarding the key lookup, that is required in order check the residual predicate `IsCalculated=1`:

[image: Screenshot of key lookup doing a residual predicate]

You can avoid the lookup by adding `IsCalculated` to the `INCLUDE` list for the `<IDX_DownloadDataSubHourly>` index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<IDX_DownloadDataSubHourly>]
ON dbo.SubHourlyMeasurementData (...)
INCLUDE (..., IsCalculated);
```

If that predicate is used a lot, and it's fairly selective, you might consider creating a filtered index for it (or adding `WHERE IsCalculated=1` to the current nonclustered index, but that might break other queries trying to use it).